# Code in Firefox about:config variable - what does it do?

Tags: firefox, obfuscation

Firefox is misbehaving, so I was looking around in about:config, and I stumbled upon something that looks like code. It was in a config variable called  `extentions.5103ad57a64ad.scode`. I'm not familiar with the environment in which this code might run, and it seems to me that it is somewhat obfuscated, but I figure there must be someone here who can figure it out.

For readability, I've put in newlines after most semicolons, and in a few other places; originally, the code was all in one long line.
I'm having trouble with pasting the code and getting the formatting right, so I've uploaded the code to Dropbox here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/86984895/ff_code.txt

Since my first guess is that the code is malicious, I cleared the variable. It has since reset itself. I do have an idea of how to clean my machine of any malware I may have caught, but I'm still interested in knowing what this code would do, if it were run.

Comment: Do I just double post the same question over there, or is there a way to move this?

Comment: Mods can move it (and will do so as soon as they see it).

Comment: Ok, I'll wait for that to happen then. Sorry for posting in the wrong place, and thanks for letting me know so quickly. :)

Comment: @MartinBüttner I've flagged it for moderator attention. Gibson, you may want to improve the quality of the question to get a good response on stackoverflow. "something like" extensions is pretty vague. Also, why are you interested in what this file contains?

Comment: How is FF misbehaving? (Not that misbehaving is a surprise, if you routinely change configuration variables about which you know nothing.)  Or is that not relevant, in your opinion?  Not sure from your question.

Comment: @Smandoli FF is misbehaving by using the wrong search engine when I type something that's not a URL in the address bar. But this question is about what the code does, not how to fix the problem that caused me to find the code.

Comment: Somehow I sounded a bit less polite than I meant to.  It must be my natural rudeness.  Thanks for reply.

Comment: gibson, do you have any suspicious plugins installed? What's the name of the search engine?

Comment: @waylon531 No suspicious plugins currently installed, though I have seen some in the past. The search engine is www.allaannonser.se.

Comment: try searching for that address in about:config

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have the IETab plus addon installed, which installs adware. When you go to a google page this addon shows price comparison information.

You should uninstall IE Tab Plus and install IE Tab 2, found here:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/92382/

Or, if you can, don't install IE Tab at all.